# Mobile navigation suddenly broken

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation

Hi all website has a mobile navigation system that has randomly stopped working.

I would really appreciate it if someone understood or that knows why this is happening to let me know

ok so what I have been using is

```
$(".click").click(function() {
        $('#menu').slideToggle ();
    });
```

This has been working fine for some time and now all of a sudden, the menu slides down and then disappears, but the links are still there and clickable

I have worked out that the element that the nav is sitting in is growing with the slideToggle, but then shrinking again, leaving only the menu behind

[Web site](http://www.rebelrunnersmedway.co.uk)

Comment: add the relevant code parts to question. StackExchange is also not an IT dep replacement for bug tracking from random sites.

Comment: I would but I don't know what part is relevant as it has only suddenly started happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

elements had a float left on, which is making them have no height and therefore nothing for the background to grow into.

change the

elements' display to inline-block and remove the float.